# Trying to use non verified REST URL in flutter application

Tags: flutter

I have deployed an application in local machine. And the REST API is enabled with self signed certificate.

In same machine flutter application running via emulator and trying to access the REST API for e.g. https://locahost:8080/uri

Flutter code that i am using as below:

```
Future<http.Response> makeHttpRequest(String method, String uri, {dynamic body}) async {
  String requestUrl = '$serverUrl/$uri';

  // Use the http package's post method for making requests
  http.Response response;
  if (method == 'POST') {
    response = await http.post(Uri.https(requestUrl), body: body);
  } else {
    response = await http.get(Uri.https(requestUrl));
  }

  return response;
}
```

But problem is its not calling to the server.

tried above mentioned code but not working.
not sure how to call it.

Comment: Do you have internet permission on the manifest?

Comment: Yes internet connection is there.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in your case? The request is not going through?

Comment: Yes request is not going through. So far i got to know if i could make insucure rest call it should work. But not sure how to set that parameter in flutter http library.